# Get local timezone in django

Tags: python, django

I have a mysql `DATETIME` value that is stored in system time, UTC. I need to convert that to my local timezone in django. Here is what I currently have:

```
# value in mysql
`timestamp`
2013-02-01 22:48:45

# settings.py
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles'

# views.py
last_updated = PathLastUpdated.objects.all()[0].timestamp
print last_updated
2013-02-01 22:48:45 <-- same as UTC
```

How would I get the last_updated value to be in my local timezone = "America/Los Angeles" ?

Comment: By "my local timezone" do you mean the timezone the server runs in or the timezone of the client which views the page?

Comment: The timezone that I have set in `settings.py` = 'America/Los_Angeles'

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The [Django documentation for timezones](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#time-zones) documents all the necessary details for converting `datetime` objects to the appropriate time zone for display.

Your data is stored in UTC which is good.  When you obtain a `DateTime` field object from the database it will be a naive `datetime.datetime` object.  ie A date/time without a timezone attached.  It's then up to you to do the conversion.

User of your webapp may be in different time zones so the conversion to an appropriate time zone must occur for *each request*.  This is why there is an [activate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.activate) function to set the current time zone.

If you have [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) installed you should be able to do the following:

```
from django.utils.timezone import activate
activate(settings.TIME_ZONE)
```

All output of date field in the template engine will then automatically convert you naive date time objects to the correct time zone for display.

If you just have a single naive `datetime.datetime` instance that you want to set the time zone on, then just use the `pytz` module directly.  It is not normal to do this in your views though, as it's a good idea to only convert the time zone at the point of presentation.

```
from pytz import timezone

settings_time_zone = timezone(settings.TIME_ZONE)
last_updated = last_updated.astimezone(settings_time_zone)
```

Comment: if `last_updated` is not in utc then change the last line to: `last_updated_in_tz = tz.normalize(last_updated.astimezone(tz))`. if `last_updated` is a naive datetime object then make it aware before calling `.astimezone()`: `aware_dt = naive_utc_dt.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)` (note: `.replace()` works only for utc, use `aware_dt = some_tz.localize(naive_dt, is_dst=None)` otherwise).

Comment: by doing "activate(settings.TIME_ZONE)" it occurs settings is not defined. I have define my TIME_ZONE = 'UTC' on settings.py. Where am i suppose to define TIME_ZONE?

Comment: @MrMartin You will need to import the Django settings module as per https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code

Comment: How can I use this but building an API?

Comment: @Gocht For APIs, the entity making the request must provide information about their time zone for you to be able to convert to their time zone.  This could be achieved by using a field in the request which can be set to indicate time zone, or use of a separate request header.

Answer (score 36):

After cry a lot, I could show the correct date for my country doing something like this:

```
>>> from django.utils.timezone import get_current_timezone
>>> from front.models import Training

>>> tz = get_current_timezone()
>>> stored_date = Training.objects.first().start_date
datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 25, 17, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)

>>> desired_date = stored_date + tz.utcoffset(stored_date)
datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 25, 14, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

The `tzinfo` attribute is shows utc, but the date and time is correct to show.

**UPDATE 30/10/2015** (Django 1.8)

I'm using another approach today, that is more django friendly

```
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> from trainings.models import Training
>>> value = Training.objects.first().date

>>> value
datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 23, 11, 32, 54, 633151, tzinfo=<UTC>)

>>> timezone.localtime(value)
datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 23, 9, 32, 54, 633151, tzinfo=<django.utils.timezone.LocalTimezone object at 0x7fa6129784a8>)
```

Comment: The UPDATE information worked for me in django 3. thanks

Answer (score 19):

**localtime** is a template filter, this may be helpful.

https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8.4/django/utils/timezone.py#L298

Code sample:

```
from django.utils.timezone import localtime 

desired_datetime = localtime(stored_datetime)
```

Answer (score 9):

I personally would advice against using a `TIME_ZONE` setting other than UTC. I remember having problems with this in the past, be it that the database was operating in a different timezone (saving values in a different timezone) than the Django backend was using. That meant a lot of hassle to compare the times, changing them forth and back depending on what you are doing.

A good practice is usually to use one timezone in the backend (lets say UTC) and convert the time in the frontend to the users timezone you are serving.

Comment: I agree with you. I am also getting problem with other timezone. But When I am sending the date from browser it is not get converted into UTC, Can you suggest me a proper way?

Comment: I would need more information about how you send the date from the browser (the format would be important, is there timezone information saved within this format). If the date is send from the browser you have to convert it into UTC using Django. I'd suggest a library like https://labix.org/python-dateutil to do this.

Comment: Thanks for reply, The problem is solve now but I dont know is it correct way or not, because I am new to Django & python. Currently I am doing this way. I pick date & time from jQuery-datepicker and converting into UTC time using Javascript, and it sends to server. I had tried with pytz libs but there was an issue with identifying from which timezone the date-time is coming. which was creating problem to convert in UTC. I dont know I am right or wrong, Please suggest what will be the right approach to do.

Comment: That approach certainly works, but you are putting more logic on the client. Usually I would put the date conversion on the server instead. Though again, if it works for you it is fine. It is definitely not a wrong approach.

Comment: Thank you, I will change it to server side.

Answer (score 7):

I've created a simple middleware to handle all of this stuff for you:

https://github.com/Miserlou/django-easy-timezones

Simply install it and follow the instructions and you're done!

1. Install django-easy-timezones

   ```
   pip install django-easy-timezones pytz pygeoip
   ```
2. Add "easy-timezones" to your INSTALLED_APPS setting like this:

   ```
   INSTALLED_APPS = (
   ...
   'easy-timezones',
   )
   ```
3. Add EasyTimezoneMiddleware to your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES

   ```
   MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
   ...
   'easy-timezones.middleware.EasyTimezoneMiddleware',
   )
   ```
4. Add a path to the [MaxMind GeoIP database](http://www.maxmind.com/en/geolocation_landing) in your settings file:

   ```
   GEOIP_DATABASE = '/path/to/your/geoip/database/GeoIP.dat'
   ```
5. Enable localtime in your templates.

   ```
   {% load tz %}
       The UTC time is {{ object.date }}
   {% localtime on %}
       The local time is {{ object.date }}
   {% endlocaltime %}
   ```
6. Tada!

Comment: According to your answer,i have set easy time zone in my django app,but if want to run my app from terminal i am getting an error saying "no module named easy_timezones"  though i have installed the package using pip. @Rich Jones

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS and MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES should use "easy_timezones", not "easy-timezones" - it is correct in your readme, but not in this answer.

Comment: @Rich Jones How to implement this if I am using DRF and angularJS for front-end? Basically I am not using Django template. Using DRF, Postgres, Django1.8 on server side and AngularJS/HTML on front-end side.

Comment: It looks like it doesn't work with Django 4.1.1

Answer (score 5):

I have came to the same problem. In my settings, I have set the `TIME_ZONE`, but the time in MySql still UTC time.

```
# settings.py
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Shanghai'
```

Then I found,in settings.py, `USE_TZ` has be set to False

`USE_TZ = False`

As pointed out by @MagicLAMP, it only works for single time zone site, please check [time-zones](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/timezones/#time-zoness)!) if your site is international or if daylight savings happen where your site is used.

Comment: This turns off time zone information, which is not a good idea if your site is international or if daylight savings happen where your site is used. Read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/timezones/#time-zones

Answer (score 5):

Just use

```
timezone.localtime(arg)
```

Answer (score 4):

It took me a while to find this, but this is how I solved it. I guess the user's timezone from IP address and then do this in Django 2 and beyond:

```
{% load tz %}
{% timezone "Europe/Paris" %}
    Paris time: {{ object.date }}
{% endtimezone %}
```

Answer (score 1):

1: Define the timezone in your view

```
from django.utils import timezone

variable = timezone.now()
```

2: Then use it in your template

```
{% load l10n %}

Teresina, {{variable |localize}}.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found easy solution based on [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-template-tags/).

Here is my `settings.py`:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

In my model named Marker I save datetime as `2022-09-15 17:56:26.936210`:

```
class Marker(models.Model):
    ....
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=now, verbose_name="Date")
```

Next I create a new **Python package** with custom template filter using a path `project/app/templatetags/some_file_name.py`

In `some_file_name.py` we do register a filter and write it's behavior:

```
from django import template
from django.utils.formats import date_format

register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def to_user_tz_short(dt):
    """Format UTC timestamp from DB to local user's short datetime format with appropriate timezone."""
    user_tz = date_format(
        dt.astimezone(), format="SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT", use_l10n=True
    )
    return user_tz
```

Next load our filter in template with code:

```
{% load some_file_name %}
```

And finally apply filter to item:

```
{{ marker.created_at|to_user_tz_short }}
```

So, in my case the datetime is save in DB as I mentioned earlier like `2022-09-15 17:56:26.936210` and after filtering, in template it shows as `15.09.2022 20:56` according to my local time zone and date format.

Before filter: `2022-09-15 17:56:26.936210` After filter -> `15.09.2022 20:56`

Answer (score 0):

I set the local timezone on a user's homepage by using time module
`timely = time.time() text = time.ctime(timely) context = {'time':text} render(request, 'home.html',context)`