# Displaying local time using DateTimeFields in Jinja2 templates - Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, jinja2

When using Django and Jinja2, it seems that `datetime` objects don't get converted to the local timezone automatically, even if `USE_TZ=True`. Instead, the value remains in UTC.

I was able to solve this by creating a filter that runs `localtime()` on the values.

However, I am not sure how to do the same thing with `DateTimeFields`. In the template, I have `{{ field }}`, where field is the `DateTimeField`, but there is nowhere to put a filter.

What is the best way to convert `DateTimeField` values to the current timezone?

Comment: Who's current timezone? The server, or the web browser?

Comment: The server's timezone as returned by `timezone.get_current_timezone()`

Comment: Ahh..Check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657173/get-local-timezone-in-django

Comment: @user590028, that works for normal Django templates, but not for Jinja2 templates.

Answer (score 7):

Thankfully this is a relatively easy fix. Django provides a function named `template_localtime` that (according to the documentation) does the following:

> "Checks if value is a datetime and converts it to local time if necessary."

Exposing this to Jinja2 templates involves either the creation of a template filter or a global function. This example demonstrates both:

```
from django.utils.timezone import template_localtime

env = Environment(**kwargs)
env.filters.update({
    'localtime': template_localtime,
})
env.globals.update({
    'localtime': template_localtime,
})
```

You can then use these in a Jinja2 template as follows:

```
{{ item.date|localtime }}
{{ localtime(item.date) }}
```