# Add datetime object without timezone

Tags: django

i wanna add datetime object which i create from user input. But i wanna add this without timezone only in this model. I tried few different way but none working.

models.py

```
class troops_command(models.Model):       
    datetime = models.DateTimeField('ki')
```

How i create object:

```
    datetime_object = datetime_module.datetime.strptime(datetime_string, format_datetime)
    import pytz
    datetime_object = pytz.timezone("Europe/London").localize(datetime_object, is_dst=None)
```

After this:

```
>>> print(datetime_object)
2014-11-22 14:49:00+00:00
```

But when i add this to database:

```
Troops_command_model.objects.create(datetime=datetime)
```

Database return:

```
2014-11-22 15:49:00+01
```

settings.py

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Warsaw'
```

Comment: But your `datetime_object` does have a timezone, `Europe/London`. Do you mean that you want it to be stored in UTC (that is, have a timezone offset of 0)? It will always be stored in UTC, and you have control over what timezone is displayed to the user. Don't worry about what's printed at the console, that is database-dependent on not relevant to what the user sees.

Comment: Yes but London have +0 so in DB should +0 not +1... I found solution, look on my new post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just create custom model field :) Easy and simple.

```
class MytypeField(models.Field):
    def db_type(self, connection):
        return 'timestamp'

class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    something_else = MytypeField()
```

"timestamp" is for postgresql, for mysql should "datetime"

Comment: this way is not database agnostic anymore?

Answer (score 1):

## settings.py

**CONST USE_TZ**

> **USE_TZ**
> Default: False
> A boolean that specifies if datetimes will be timezone-aware by default or not. If this is set to True, Django will use timezone-aware datetimes internally. Otherwise, Django will use naive datetimes in local time.
>
> The default **settings.py** file created by django-admin.py startproject includes USE_TZ = True for convenience.

So, you can change this settings, look more [django settings docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#std:setting-USE_TZ)

## UPDATE!

***Try to use [enter link description here](https://github.com/mfogel/django-timezone-field). Or try to create custom field with pytz -> [tutorial](http://reliablybroken.com/b/2009/06/django-and-time-zone-aware-date-fields/)***

Comment: Yea but i have others model where i need timezone.

Comment: @KozakPoprostu Mmmm, u need 1 modet with out timezone. And others are with?

Comment: exactly yes. And i need this to be datetime object.

Comment: @KozakPoprostu You understand what timezone does not know about settings.py :)

Comment: @KozakPoprostu Ok, sorry for flood. Firstly => you can use this [django-timezone-field](https://github.com/mfogel/django-timezone-field). Secondly => Ovveride with pytz. Some like this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657173/get-local-timezone-in-django). Of course first solution better =)

Comment: I found better solution :) Look on my new post.