# Python / Django templates timezone issue

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone

I am having the following issue, and cant figure out what i am missing here.

I have enabled the Timezone in the settings.py

### Settings.py

`TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'`

`USE_TZ = True`

### Use-case

Now, when I have created an object at 3.15pm (Local time), and i get the following date stored in my `created_at` field in database.

`created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`

`2014-12-12 11:03:48`

When i render that date in my templates i get the following value.

`{{ image.created_at }}` = >
`Dec. 12, 2014, 5:03 a.m.`

### TEST CASE

```
    from datetime import datetime
    from dateutil.tz import tzutc, tzlocal

    utc = datetime.now(tzutc())
    print('UTC:   ' + str(utc))

    local = utc.astimezone(tzlocal())
    print('Local: ' + str(local))
```

I am getting correct datetime here. And when i use `myobject.created_at.astimezone(tzlocal())` it also returns correct. but its when in Templates i get 1 hour ahead time. WHY? i tried both `|local` filter also but no use

What am I missing?

Comment: Is your server actually in the Chicago timezone?

Comment: Well i have defined the time zone in the settings.py as `TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'`. i think this is default settings.

Comment: the 'TIME_ZONE` should reflect your actual time zone. ie the clock of the machine running django

Comment: Thats what is dynamic. When someone open the application in USA he would get the time accordingly like the one who open in UK. so i can not set it to any spcific time zone. getting?

Answer (score 11):

Add the below snippet to the base.html

```
{% load tz %}

{% timezone "Asia/Kolkata" %}
  <All content goes here>
{% endtimezone %}
```

Inherit this to all templates. Everything render in 'Asia/Kolkata' time zone

Answer (score 6):

Django always stores data in UTC with timezone aware info. Your settings.py is for America/Chicago therefore template renders it accordingly.

You can use timezone filters in your template to always show local time `{{ image.created_at | localtime }}`.  At template start do `{% load tz %}` timezone tag library.

I.e.

```
{% load tz %}

<!-- template -->

{{ image.created_at | localtime }}

<!-- more template -->
```

Comment: As per testcase code I get expected timezone in template, no variation of 1 hr. Please share exact template code.

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#std:templatefilter-localtime):

**localtime**

Forces conversion of a single value to the current time zone.

For example:

```
{% load tz %}

{{ value|localtime }}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `TIME_ZONE` setting is for the default (usually sever location timezone) to display time information related to the logged user you should read the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone)

Answer (score 0):

I found easy way to do it with custom template filter, please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736373/17176270).

Before filter: `2022-09-15 17:56:26.936210` After filter -> `15.09.2022 20:56`