# Django timezone.now() giving wrong time

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

thanks for your time.
i've got a model Profile thats linked on User. And a Hours models thats linked on Profile.

By every time a user login a Hours object should be created with the loging_in field automatically set to timezone.now().

I've tried timezone.now(), datetime.now(), timezone.localtime(timezone.now()). Tried all of them on default of loging_in field and on login_view. every try creates the object as i want. But every time gives me the wrong time about 20 minutes earlier or later.

So i'd like to know what am i doing wrong and whats the best way to set this (models or views).

settings.py:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pt-br'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Sao_Paulo'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = False

USE_TZ = True

DATETIME_FORMAT = "d/m/Y H:s"
```

models.py:

```
class Hours(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='hours', null=True)
    loging_in = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.localtime(timezone.now()))
    loging_out = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    done = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    delta = models.DurationField(default=datetime.timedelta(hours=0))
    objects = HoursManager()
```

views.py:

```
def login_view(request):
    if not request.user.is_anonymous:
        logout_view(request)
    else:
        # raise ValidationError('DESLOGUE PRIMEIRO')
        next = request.GET.get('next')
        form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
        # se estiver escrito certo#
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            # autenticando o usuario#
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            # se estiver tudo certo (autendicado) chamar a função login#
            login(request, user)
            p1, status = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
            h1 = Hours.objects.create(profile=p1)
            if next:
                return redirect(next)
            return redirect('/accounts/profile/{}'.format(p1.id))
        context = {
            'form': form,
        }
        return render(request, "admin/login.html", context)
```

Comment: does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657173/get-local-timezone-in-django?answertab=active#tab-top) is your question ?

Comment: ill try following the way that he explained but i guess it dont. i'm beeing able to convert and render timezone to each country (tested with VPN) the real problem is that i dont know why when i LOGIN should create a Hour object to the exact time. but its getting me 20 minutes earlier or later.

Comment: Your settings look good. For your loging_in attribute you can use [auto_now_add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add). If then your time is still 20 minutes earlier you can check your server time. Perhaps it just is not in sync with your local time?

Comment: i've tried auto_now and auto_now_add it didnt worked either. On the logs shows me the exact time of my pc and local. Is there other way to check my server time?

Comment: `timedatectl` or `date` command in ubuntu. in windows cmd `time /T` and `tzutil /g`, powershell `Get-TimeZone`